# Is this a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

I know a complete graph must have a edge between every pair of vertices, so I just wanted to make sure whether the below was a complete graph or not? I am guessing it isn't because there is no edge between D and E, or B and F. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: it is not complete. In fact the complete graph on $6$ vertices would have $\binom62=15$ edges, and this graph has only $8$ edges.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @JimmyK: You’re welcome!